# local.ERROR: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1615 Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared in happen in every morning

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

My **laravel** project is getting error every morning, and after some time it becomes okay. I don't understand what is the issue.

I googled it and see some similar issues. But it does not resolve my issue.

```
db version is 5.1.1
```

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42041

Comment: Is there any problem while updating mysql version!

Comment: read the release notes and find out if it would affect you or not.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES of PDO (disabled by default at Laravel) for resolve the problem. Just insert the option config:

```
'options'   => [
        \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
       ]
```

For example

```
  'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
        'options'   => [
            \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
        ]
    ],
```

Comment: I saw this answer but their they mention it is not proper solution for this. It is just temporary solution